# How to render form elements in view?

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms, element

I have created a form like this:

```
class Form_Login extends Zend_Form {

    public function __construct() {

        $this->setMethod('post');
        $elements = array();

        // username
        $element = $this->addElement('text', 'username', array('label' => 'Username') );
        $elements[] = $element;

        // password
        $element = $this->addElement('password', 'password', array('label' => 'Password'));
        $elements[] = $element;

        // submit 
        $element = $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Login'));
        $elements[] = $element;

        $this->addElements( $elements );
        $this->addDecorator('ViewHelper');
        $this->setDecorators(array(array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'authentication/login-form.phtml' ))));   
    }
}
```

Now in **login-form.phtml** file I render elements like this:

```
<form action='submitlogin' method='post' id='loginform'>  

Login Form

<?=  $this->form->getElement('username');  ?>
<?=  $this->form->getElement('password');  ?>

</form>
```

It gives me following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getElement() on a non-object in
/var/www/student/application/views/scripts/authentication/login-form.phtml on line 5
```

How to render elements in external script...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call elements from the view scripts like this:

```
<?= $this->element->username ?>
```

For specific element components you can use the next things:

```
<? $el = $this->element->username; ?>
<label><?= $el->getLabel() ?></label>
<?= $this->formText($el->getName(), $el->getValue(), $el->getAttribs()) ?>
```

Comment: +1 ok. It is rendering label and textfield together with your above answer. How can I render label and textfield separately. Thanks

Comment: Please note that 'element' in $this->element->username refers to the form object, not an actual element. $this->element->username then refers to the Form_Element object. Just a little coding convention.

Comment: After some time I found a short and complete solution of my problem. See my answer also.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is my complete solution:

Form Class in **Login.php**:

```
class Form_Login extends Zend_Form {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct( $options = null ) {

        parent::__construct( $options );

        // Set the method for the display form to POST
        $this->setMethod('post');

        $elements = array();

        $element = $this->CreateElement('text', 'username');
        $element->setLabel('Username');
        $elements[] = $element;

        $element = $this->CreateElement('password', 'password');
        $element->setLabel('Password');
        $elements[] = $element;

        $element = $this->CreateElement('submit', 'submit');
        $element->setLabel('Login');
        $elements[] = $element;

        $this->addElements( $elements );

        $this->setElementDecorators( array( 'ViewHelper' ) );

        $this->setDecorators( array( array( 'ViewScript', array( 'viewScript' => 'authentication/login-form.phtml' ) ) ) );

    } // end construct


} // end class
```

**login-form.phtml**

```
<form action=<?= $this->element->getAction() ?> method=<?= $this->element->getMethod() ?> >


<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label><?= $this->element->username->getLabel() ?></label></td>
        <td><?= $this->element->username; ?></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td><label><?= $this->element->password->getLabel() ?></label></td>
        <td><?= $this->element->password; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form>
```